# How to find index when drag and drop between 2 containers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to perform Jquery drag and drop option between to container. But i am not able to find the items exact index when it dropped. While doing within the container its fine. For each container its starting index from 0. Thats the problem.

My code is as follows:

```
 <% all_tasks.each do |due_date, tasks| %>

 <h3 class="task_active task_plus_ico">
  <%=Date.today.to_s == due_date.to_s ? t("Due Today") : t(due_date_format[0]).concat("," + due_date_format[1])%>
 </h3>
 <div class="task_column_details sortable" style="display:none;">
 <% tasks.each do |t| %>
 <p><%= t.name %></p>
 <%end%>
</div>
 <%end%>
```

And my Jquery code is as follows:

```
  $( ".sortable" ).sortable({
  revert: true,
  connectWith  : ".sortable",
  update: function(event, ui) { 
  alert(ui.item.index()) // its giving index starting from 0 for each container. but i want continuous index
  },
```

The UI is looks as follows:

[image]

Please help me to find the index or the container name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, when you drop from 1st container to 2nd container you want to get the index of the dropped item as number of items in 1st container + index of item in 2nd container.

You can use something like this. `.sortable('toArray')` will return the items in the container as an array. `ui.sender` refers to the 1st container the item was dragged from.

```
$('.sortable').sortable({
    connectWith: '.sortable',
    update: function(event, ui) {
      var draggedto = this.id;
      var draggedFrom = $(ui.sender).attr("id");
      var totalIndex = $(ui.sender).sortable('toArray').length + ui.item.index();

    console.log({
      from: draggedFrom,
      to: draggedto,
      index: ui.item.index(),
      totalIndex: totalIndex
    });
  }
});
```

You need to check if ui.sender is null or not I think.

Comment: is there any way to find moved container name?

Comment: `this` is the container you dropped to, so you can get any attributes you want, i.e. $(this).attr("name") etc.

Comment: i am not getting the container name. please help me

Comment: Post your html in your question. I don't know how you're storing the name. What I posted should be enough though.

Comment: Actually the container code is placed outside of sortable div.

Comment: Shouldn't matter really as `ui.sender` inside the update would refer to the source container.

Comment: update: event is running two times. i want only second time value. how to do thaT?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63152/discussion-between-pooja-agarwal-and-artm).

Comment: @poojaagarwal Event runs twice, one for the source container, and one for the target container. You need to put checks inside the handler to see which is which.

Comment: how to put? please help me. this is my last question.

Comment: You can use `if (ui.sender) { console.log...`, meaning if it's coming from another container.. If ui.sender is null then it's the target.